# How to remove compatibility level on subject level

Tags: confluent-schema-registry

I added compatibility level FULL on a subject and now I want it removed, so the schema-registry compatibility level (global compatibility level) is used. How can it be done?
According to the [documentation updating compatibility level for the specified subject](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#put--config-(string-%20subject)) is done by 'PUT /config/(string: subject)' + `{"compatibility": "FULL"}`.

When I try:

```
{
  "compatibility": ""
}
```

as body it returns :

```
{
    "error_code": 42203,
    "message": "Invalid compatibility level. Valid values are none, backward, forward and full"
}
```

and if I try empty body:

```
{
    "error_code": 422,
    "message": "updateSubjectLevelConfig.arg3 may not be null (was null)"
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I checked out [schema registry code](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry) and in [ConfigResource](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/rest/resources/ConfigResource.java#L94-L95) compatibility level received from the request and is parsed against a [CompatibilityLevel enum](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/CompatibilityLevel.java). So, it is either a valid config (none, full...) or exception is thrown (when null). Also, I couldn't find any other rest end point in [rest resources](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/rest/resources/) that can allow the deletion of this configuration.